Ansible use connection: local option along with jump ssh
How to make Ansible use jump server ssh when there is the "connection: local" instruction?
Ex:
- name: snmp
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  serial: 1
  tasks:
  - name: Gather facts with SNMP version 2
    community.general.snmp_facts:
      host: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
      version: v2c
      community: public
    vars:
      ansible_python_interpreter: /var/local/meteor/ansible/.venv/bin/python

In the example, it works for devices on the local network, but I need to contact a device that is only reachable using an SSH Jump, this is possible with other modules, but I couldn't with "community.general.snmp_facts"

https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2022/using-ansible-playbook-ssh-bastion-jump-host should help

Thanks for the suggestion
It is precisely this technique that I use when the destinations are normal machines, but in this case it is only the intermediate machine (jump) that would use ssh, and from there execute the queries via snmp.
